# can't echo php class variable

Tags: php, class, variables

I want to write a php simple pagination class. Here is my code:

```
<?php
class Pagination {
public $rowsPerPage;
public $currentPage;
public $totalPages;
public $totalRows;
public $firstElement;
public $lastElement;


     public function paginate()
        { 
            if(isset($_GET['page'])){
                $this->currentPage  = $_GET['page'];     
            }           

                         $this->totalPages =  $this->totalRows/$this->rowsPerPage  ;
             return $this->totalPages;  

              $this->firstElement = $this->currentPage-1)*$this->rowsPerPage+1;
              return $this->firstElement;                
        }
}

$totalRecords = 55;
$paginator = new Pagination();
$paginator->totalRows = $totalRecords;
$paginator->rowsPerPage = 5;
$paginator->paginate();
echo $paginator->totalPages;
echo $paginator->firstElement;  
?>
```

I can echo $paginator->totalPages; but not $paginator->firstElement.
What I do wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: I have also _construct function

public function _construct() {
   $this->rowsPerPage = 5;
                        $this->currentPage  = 1;        
            $this->totalPages   = 0;
   $this->totalRows    = 40;
   $this->firstElement = 0;
   $this->lastElement = 0;
   
 }

Comment: There is a syntatic error over ther in $this->firstElement you have a closing parenthesis, but not a opening.

Comment: Turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/error+reporting).

Answer (score 8):

Your `paginate` function has two `return` statements.

When the code hits the `return $this->totalPages;`, it will stop running the function.  Therefore, the `$this->firstElement = ...` line is never ran.